# Как в Битриксе перенести «Умный фильтр»?

Tags: битрикс

Возникла проблема с перемещением "Умного фильтра", который выводится через компонент bitrix:catalog. Данный фильтр выводится автоматом в правой части включаемой области вместе с разделами инфоблока, как его вывести на включаемой области общего шаблона сайта. Официальная техподдержка Битрикс не смогла оказать помощь в этом вопросе.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Возьмите компонент умного фильтра и вызовите в нужном месте? Не умеете этого делать? Читайте документацию.

Comment: И да компонент умного фильтра это `bitrix:catalog.smart.filter` и он просто входит в комплексный компонент каталога, но никто не мешает вам его использовать отдельно в нужном месте сайта настроив его.

Comment: Фильтр перенёс с помощью отложенных функций. Только после переноса фильтра осталось пустое место, не подскажите как его убрать?

Comment: уберите код вызова компонента фильтра из комплексного компонента и отредактируйте шаблон и стили чтобы вывод товаров занимал это место.

Comment: Когда убираю код вызова компонента фильтра место под него пропадает и товары занимают всю область как и надо, однако фильтр перестаёт выводится и в той области куда был перенесён.

Comment: Поэтому надо сделать как я указал вам вышел. Разместить код вызова компонента в нужном месте. В настройках компонента правильно указать результирующую страницу.